# Loading data for GCC's vector extensions

Tags: gcc, checksum, vectorization, simd

GCC's [vector extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) offer a nice, reasonably portable way of accessing some SIMD instructions on different hardware architectures without resorting to [hardware specific intrinsics](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Target-Builtins.html) (or auto-vectorization).

A real use case, is calculating a simple additive checksum. The one thing that isn't clear is how to safely load data into a vector.

```
typedef char v16qi __attribute__ ((vector_size(16)));

static uint8_t checksum(uint8_t *buf, size_t size)
{
    assert(size%16 == 0);
    uint8_t sum = 0;

    vec16qi vec = {0};
    for (size_t i=0; i<(size/16); i++)
    {
        // XXX: Yuck! Is there a better way?
        vec += *((v16qi*) buf+i*16);
    }

    // Sum up the vector
    sum = vec[0] + vec[1] + vec[2] + vec[3] + vec[4] + vec[5] + vec[6] + vec[7] + vec[8] + vec[9] + vec[10] + vec[11] + vec[12] + vec[13] + vec[14] + vec[15];

    return sum;
}
```

Casting a pointer to the vector type appears to work, but I'm worried this might explode in a horrible fashion if SIMD hardware expects the vector types to be correctly aligned.

The only other option I've thought of is use a temp vector and explicitly load the values (via either a memcpy or element-wise assignment), but in testing this counteract most of speedup gained use of SIMD instructions. Ideally I'd imagine this would be something like a generic `__builtin_load()` function, but none seems to exist.

What's a safer way of loading data into a vector risking alignment issues?

Comment: Running this on unaligned memory on GCC x86_64 will cause a SIGSEGV when the CPU attempts to load the unaligned memory into a SSE register.

One reasonable option seems to be either only checksum aligned memory or use a normal loop to sum the bytes up until the first 16 byte boundary.

Comment: In your current code, loading the data actually compiles nicely if the compiler knows about the input (but the sum is bad): https://godbolt.org/g/DeR3Qv. It's not so nice without knowledge of the input: https://godbolt.org/g/LxEkhp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an initializer to load the values, i.e. do

```
const vec16qi e = { buf[0], buf[1], ... , buf[15] }
```

and hope that GCC turns this into a SSE load instruction. I'd verify that with a dissassembler, though ;-). Also, for better performance, you try to make `buf` 16-byte aligned, and inform that compiler via an `aligned` attribute. If you can guarantee that the input buffer will be aligned, process it bytewise until you've reached a 16-byte boundard.

Comment: I don't think aligning buf is necessary. It would be, if we were dealing with pointers.

Comment: @user1095108 You want the compiler to turn this into an SSE load instruction, which is the equivalent of `e = *buf`(but you can't write it that way because the types don't match). So you ARE dealing with pointers here, actually. If the compiler can infer that buf is 16-byte aligned it can thus use an aligned load, which (pre ivy-bridge, at least) is faster than an unaligned load.

Comment: No, you'd be dealing with pointers if you were to cast `buf` to `vec16qi` from my experience.

Comment: @user1095108 You missunderstood me, I think. You of course aren't dealing with pointers, *strictly speaking*. But you're loading a values (16 values, actually) *pointed to* by `buf, which is *exactly* what dereferencing a pointer (of type vec16qi) would do. Now, since we're not *strictly speaking* dereferencing `buf`, the pointer doesn't *have* to be aligned for correctness. *But* it might still make a huge difference in performance - and it indeed does on some CPUs. That's assuming the compiler even turns this into an SSE load instructions.

Comment: On my machine, I only see alignment issues when dealing with pointers directly, not when dereferencing them while loading them into a vector.

Comment: GCC7 doesn't seem to do anything smart with the syntax in this answer: https://godbolt.org/g/epocpU. Each byte is moved with `movzbl`. Not sure if some alignment hints would do the trick but doesn't look likely.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit** (thanks Peter Cordes) You can cast pointers:

```
typedef char v16qi __attribute__ ((vector_size (16), aligned (16)));

v16qi vec = *(v16qi*)&buf[i]; // load
*(v16qi*)(buf + i) = vec; // store whole vector
```

This compiles to `vmovdqa` to load and `vmovups` to store. If the data isn't known to be aligned, set `aligned (1)` to generate `vmovdqu`. ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/Utb5hp))

Note that there are also several special-purpose builtins for loading and unloading these registers (**Edit 2**):

```
v16qi vec = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&buf[i]); // _mm_load_si128 for aligned
_mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&buf[i]), vec); // _mm_store_si128 for aligned
```

It seems to be necessary to use `-flax-vector-conversions` to go from `char`s to `v16qi` with this function.

See also: [C - How to access elements of vector using GCC SSE vector extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771945/c-how-to-access-elements-of-vector-using-gcc-sse-vector-extension)
See also: [SSE loading ints into __m128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437599/sse-loading-ints-into-m128)

(Tip: The best phrase to google is something like "gcc loading __m128i".)

Comment: Apparently the recommended way to load unaligned data into GNU C vectors is with an `aligned(1)` attribute when declaring a vector type, and cast pointers to that unaligned-vector type.  e.g. `typedef char __attribute__ ((vector_size (16),aligned (1))) unaligned_byte16;`. See [the end of my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39115055/224132), and Marc Glisse's comments on it.

Comment: To extract, I think you should be using `vec[0]`.  As I understand it, aliasing scalar pointers onto  vector types is *not* ok.  It works with `char*` because `char*` is special, and allowed to alias anything.  Casting an `int*` to a `v4si*` doesn't even count as aliasing, because v4si is defined in terms of `int`.  The Intel intrinsics types (`__m128i`) can alias onto other things too, because of an extra attribute: `typedef long long __m128i __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));`  Without may_alias, you can't safely `v4si ivec = *(v4si)short_pointer`.  I left that out before

Comment: See `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/emmintrin.h` or wherever your copy of gcc keeps that header.

Comment: Re: extract, just realized that what I had was moving a single byte, changed back to memcpy for the moment, still digging... thanks for the tips

Comment: This issue of how to correctly get data into/out of GNU C vector extensions really seems to need a tutorial, or longer canonical answer.  I might be able to write one, but I haven't used them in any code I've written, other than experiments on Godbolt.