# SSE loading ints into __m128

Tags: c, gcc, sse, avx

What are the gcc's intrinsic for loading 4 `ints` into `__m128` and 8 ints into `__m256` (aligned/unaligned)? What about `unsigned ints`?

Comment: Clarification: You're looking GCC's intrinsics, and not Intel's intrinsics correct?

Comment: Don't know precisely, but intrinsic usable from gcc 4.6+ "out-of-box".

Comment: Use https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ to find all you need to know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Intel's SSE intrnisics, the ones you're looking for are:

- `_mm_load_si128()`
- `_mm_loadu_si128()`
- `_mm256_load_si256()`
- `_mm256_loadu_si256()`

Documentation:

- https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_load_si128
- https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_load_si256

There's no distinction between signed or unsigned. You'll need to cast the pointer to `__m128i*` or `__m256i*`.

---

Note that these are Intel's SSE intrinsics and will work in GCC, Clang, MSVC, and ICC.
The GCC intrinsics work only in, well, GCC AFAIK of.

Comment: Nice, thank you, very much. I have on other follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437860/sse-ints-vs-floats-practice