# SSE ints vs. floats practice

Tags: c, gcc, sse, simd, avx

When dealing with both ints and floats in SSE (AVX) is it a good practice to convert all ints to floats and work only with floats?
Because we need only a few SIMD instructions after that, and all we need to use is addition and compare instructions (`<, <=, ==`) which this conversion, I hope, should retain completely.

Comment: Ideally, it is nice to get rid of floats rather than ints. Ints are faster, better and stronger :)

Comment: Even on SSE??? I am not that sure. We cannot get rid of floats, obviously :) Converting int `4 -> 4.00000` is OK, but equality must be retained.

Comment: You're gonna need to show an example of what you're trying to do. `int` != `float`. And also AVX doesn't support 256-bit wide integer arithmetic yet. (AVX2 will) So I can see why you would want to do this. Whether it will be faster will be heavily dependent on what you're trying to do.

Comment: int and float are different and not interchangeable. Use the the type best represents your data.

Comment: @Mysticical: All we need are those few instructions mentioned above. We are to develop some not trivial algorithm which needs only those instructions and as input it can get `int[]` or `float[]`. So, our idea is to convert everything to `__m256` (floats) and work only on them. Would it be a good approach?

Comment: @James: Indeed. If you can use int rather than float/double, you always choose int. Be that SSE or not. Well, unless you benefit from hardware accelerator designed specifically for floats and w/o int support. Unfortunately, sometimes using fixed-point math is way to much trouble. CHASE bank, for example, once invested tons of money to get rid of floats in one of their systems, some transaction processing from ATMs + pricing analysis if I am not mistaken. Eventually they ended up with ints and FPGA.

Comment: Currently, integer SSE has higher-throughput and lower latency than FP-AVX. So if you're only doing addition and comparison, I'd stick with integer SSE over FP-AVX. You'll also get the benefit of AVX2 when that comes out. The subset of applications that benefit from using floating-point for integer arithmetic is fairly niche. (but they do indeed exist)

Comment: @Mysticial: So, you would divide our algo in two parts: int-input-version working with `__m128i` and float-input-version working with `__m256`, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expand my comments into an answer.

Basically you weighing the following trade-off:

**Stick with integer:**

- Integer SSE is low-latency, high throughput. (dual issue on Sandy Bridge)
- Limited to 128-bit SIMD width.

**Convert to floating-point:**

- Benefit from 256-bit AVX.
- Higher latencies, and only single-issue addition/subtraction (on Sandy Bridge)
- Incurs initial conversion overhead.
- Restricts input to those that fit into a `float` without precision loss.

I'd say stick with integer for now. If you don't want to duplicate code with the `float` versions, then that's your call.

The only times I've seen where emulating integers with floating-point becomes faster are when you have to do divisions.

---

Note that I've made no mention of readability as diving into manual vectorization probably implies that performance is more important.

Comment: AVX Floating-point is not single-issue on Sandy Bridge.  The exact characteristics are hard to state concisely, but Sandy Bridge can perform an FP add and multiply every cycle (as well as some combination of load, store, and permute).  For precise details, consult 2.1.4 of the Intel Optimization Manual.  (In fairness, the questioner seems to not be doing any multiplications, so you're not entirely off the mark)

Comment: I'm fully aware of the add + mul issue (along with a shuffle of some sort). But yes, I was referring to the FP-add being single-issue. (Though I admit I could've been a bit more clear on that.)