# How to concatenate two 64bits integer into a 128 bits integer?

Tags: c, concatenation, 128-bit

I have 2 64 bit integers and I would like to concatenate it into a single 128bit integer.

```
    uint64_t len_A;
    uint64_t len_C;

    len_AC= (len_A << 64) | len_C;
```

GCC doesn't support `uint128_t`.

Is there any other ways to do it?

Comment: gcc docs about 128-bit integers http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html

Comment: Store it as two `uint64_t`s, then implement operations accordingly.

Comment: You can use Intel's SSE intrinsics for 128bit.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437599/sse-loading-ints-into-m128

Answer (score 5):

First of all you should decide how you would store that 128-bit integer.
There is no built-in integer type of that dimension.

You can store the integer, for example, as a struct consisting of two 64-bit integers:

```
typedef struct { uint64_t high; uint64_t low; } int128;
```

Then the answer will be quite simple.

The question is what are you going to do with this integer next.

Comment: i will need to do a XOR operation on the resultant 128bit integer, will i still be able to use this method?

Comment: Yes, certainly. XOR is a bitwise operation. Just perform XORs on the corresponding parts, like `c.high = a.high ^ b.high; c.low = a.low ^ b.low;`.

Answer (score 2):

as Inspired said:

> The question is what are you going to do with this integer next.

You probably want to use a arbitrary precision library that handles this for you in a portable and reliable way. Why? Because you may find yourself dealing with endianess issues as in choosing the high or low end of the integer in a given hardware.

Even if you know for sure where you code will run, still you will need to develop an entire set of functions that deals with your 128-bits integer because not all the compilers support a 128-bit type, (it seems GCC does support this type of integers), for instance, you will need to create a set of functions for basic mathematic operations.

It's probably better if you use the GMP library, visit the following link for more:
http://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 1):

If your GCC does not have `uint128_t` it surely does not have 128 bits integers.

So you need to represent them e.g. with structures like

```
 struct my128int_st {
       uint64_t hi, lo;
 } ac;
 ac.hi = a;
 ac.lo = c;
```