# How to extract bytes from an SSE2 __m128i structure?

Tags: c, image-processing, vectorization, simd, sse2

I'm a beginner with SIMD intrinsics, so I'll thank everyone for their patience in advance. I have an application involving absolute difference comparison of unsigned bytes (I'm working with greyscale images).

I tried AVX, more modern SSE versions etc, but eventually decided SSE2 seems sufficient and has the most support for individual bytes - please correct me if I'm wrong.

I have two questions: first, what's the right way to load 128-bit registers? I think I'm supposed to pass the load intrinsics data aligned to multiples of 128, but will that work with 2D array code like this:

```
greys = aligned_alloc(16, xres * sizeof(int8_t*));

for (uint32_t x = 0; x < xres; x++)
{
    greys[x] = aligned_alloc(16, yres * sizeof(int8_t*));
}
```

(The code above assumes xres and yres are the same, and are powers of two). Does this turn into a linear, unbroken block in memory? Could I then, as I loop, just keep passing addresses (incrementing them by 128) to the SSE2 load intrinsics? Or does something different need to be done for 2D arrays like this one?

My second question: once I've done all my vector processing, how the heck do I extract the modified bytes from the `__m128i` ? Looking through the Intel Intrinsics Guide, instructions that convert a vector type to a scalar one are rare. The closest I've found is int `_mm_movemask_epi8 (__m128i a)` but I don't quite understand how to use it.

Oh, and one third question - I assumed `_mm_load_si128` only loads signed bytes? And I couldn't find any other byte loading function, so I guess you're just supposed to subtract 128 from each and account for it later?

I know these are basic questions for SIMD experts, but I hope this one will be useful to beginners like me. And if you think my whole approach to the application is wrong, or I'd be better off with more modern SIMD extensions, I'd love to know. I'd just like to humbly warn I've never worked with assembly and all this bit-twiddling stuff requires a lot of explication if it's to help me.

Nevertheless, I'm grateful for any clarification available.

In case it makes a difference: I'm targeting a low-power i7 Skylake architecture. But it'd be nice to have the application run on much older machines too (hence SSE2).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Least obvious question first:

> once I've done all my vector processing, how the heck do I extract the modified bytes from the `__m128i`

Extract the low 64 bits to an integer with  `int64_t _mm_cvtsi128_si64x(__m128i)`, or [the low 32 bits with `int _mm_cvtsi128_si32 (__m128i a)`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=int%2520_mm_cvt&techs=SSE2&expand=1786,1784).

If you want other parts of the vector, not the low element, your options are:

- Shuffle the vector to create a new `__m128i` with the data you want in the low element, and use the cvt intrinsics (MOVD or MOVQ in asm).
- Use SSE2 [`int _mm_extract_epi16 (__m128i a, int imm8)`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=pextrw&techs=SSE2&expand=1786,1784,2254), or the SSE4.1 similar instructions for other element sizes such as `_mm_extract_epi64(v, 1);` (PEXTRB/W/D/Q) are not the fastest instructions, but if you only need one high element, they're about equivalent to a separate shuffle and MOVD, but smaller machine code.
- `_mm_store_si128` to an aligned temporary array and access the members: compilers will often optimize this into just a shuffle or `pextr*` instruction if you compile with `-msse4.1` or `-march=haswell` or whatever.  [print a __m128i variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257166/print-a-m128i-variable/46752535#46752535) shows an example, including Godbolt compiler output showing `_mm_store_si128` into an `alignas(16) uint64_t tmp[2]`
- Or use `union { __m128i v; int64_t i64[2]; }` or something.  Union-based type punning is legal in C99, but only as an extension in C++.  This is compiles the same as a tmp array, and is generally not easier to read.

  An alternative to the union that would also work in C++ would be `memcpy(&my_int64_local,  8 + (char*)my_vector, 8);` to extract the high half, but that seems more complicated and less clear, and more likely to be something a compiler wouldn't "see through".  Compilers are usually pretty good about optimizing away small fixed-size memcpy when it's an entire variable, but this is just half of the variable.
- If the whole high half of a vector can go directly into memory unmodified (instead of being needed in an integer register), a smart compiler might optimize to use [MOVHPS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVHPS.html) to store the high half of a `__m128i` with the above union stuff.

  Or you can use `_mm_storeh_pi((__m64*)dst,  _mm_castsi128_ps(vec))`.  That only requires SSE1, and is more efficient than SSE4.1 `pextrq` on most CPUs.  But don't do this for a scalar integer you're about to use again right away; if SSE4.1 isn't available it's likely the compiler will actually MOVHPS and integer reload, which usually isn't optimal.  (And some compilers like MSVC don't optimize intrinsics.)

---

> Does this turn into a linear, unbroken block in memory?

No, it's an array of pointers to separate blocks of memory, introducing an extra level of indirection vs. a proper 2D array.  Don't do that.

Make one large allocation, and do the index calculation yourself (using `array[x*yres + y]`).

And yes, load data from it with `_mm_load_si128`, or loadu if you need to load from an offset.

---

> assumed `_mm_load_si128` only loads signed bytes

Signed or unsigned isn't an inherent property of a byte, it's only how you interpret the bits.  You use the same load intrinsic for loading two 64-bit elements, or a 128-bit bitmap.

Use intrinsics that are appropriate for your data.  It's a little bit like assembly language: everything is just bytes, and the machine will do what you tell it with your bytes.  It's up to you to choose a sequence of instructions / intrinsics that produces meaningful results.

The integer load intrinsics take `__m128i*` pointer args, so you have to use `_mm_load_si128( (const __m128i*) my_int_pointer )` or similar.  This looks like pointer aliasing (e.g. reading an array of `int` through a `short *`), which is Undefined Behaviour in C and C++.  However, this is how Intel says you're supposed to do it, so any compiler that implements Intel's intrinsics is required to make this work correctly.  gcc does so by defining `__m128i` with `__attribute__((may_alias))`.

See also [Loading data for GCC's vector extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318115/loading-data-for-gccs-vector-extensions/39608561#39608561) which points out that you can use Intel intrinsics for GNU C native vector extensions, and shows how to load/store.

---

To learn more about SIMD with SSE, there are some links in the [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) tag wiki, including some intro / tutorial links.

The [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki has some good x86 asm / performance links.

Comment: You other option is see if the compiler will vectorise it first, and then if you need more that the compiler can do, then add in intrinsics later. ideally we all use vanilla code and the compiler does SSE, AXV or whatever the machine supports if it is something that the compiler writers have set it up to optimize.

Comment: @Peter Cordez - Unfortunately, now I can't even figure out a way to load my bytes into a 16-byte vector. The load/store commands all seem to use vectors for both results and arguments - including addresses! My intuition would have been that I provide (as a load argument) an address from my byte array, but that's not possible because the load intrinsics require vectors as arguments. And I can't find an intrinsic that returns an (address) vector from a normal, scalar 64-bit address!

Comment: @sacheie: right, for integer you have to use `_mm_loadu_si128( (const __m128i*) my_int_pointer )`.  You would have found this out if you'd looked at any of the tutorials linked from the tag wikis.

Comment: Perhaps I would have; perhaps you give me too much credit ;)

In any case, I did observe that one can simply cast between vector types and arrays of scalars, which worked for me.

But sincerely, thank you for your patience Peter.

Comment: @PeterCordes - for integer you can also use `_mm_lddqu_si128()` - main difference: 'This intrinsic may perform better than _mm_loadu_si128 when the data crosses a cache line boundary.' (from the Intel reference)

Comment: @maxschlepzig: only on Pentium 4.  `lddqu` and `movdqu` run identically on all other x86 microarchitectures.  I don't think anyone cares about P4 anymore.  Using `lddqu` doesn't actually *hurt* (AFAIK), hopefully with AVX enabled, compilers can still fold unaligned `lddqu` loads into memory operands for other instructions like `vpaddb xmm0, xmm1, [unaligned_mem]`