# Compiler Support of members of SSE vector types like m128_f32[x]

Tags: visual-c++, clang, sse

This might sound stupid but is there a way to activate support of the inner members of an SSE vector type ?

I know this works fine on MSVC, And I ve found some comments on forums and SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771945/c-how-to-access-elements-of-vector-using-gcc-sse-vector-extension).
The question, is can I activate this on CLang at least without creating my own unions ?

Thank you

**[edit, workaround]**

Currently I decided to create a vec4 type to help me.
here is the code

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <cstdint>


#ifdef _WIN32
typedef __m128 vec4;
typedef __m128i vec4i;
typedef __m128d vec4d;
#else
typedef union __declspec(align(16)) vec4{
    float m128_f32[4];
    uint64_t m128_u64[2];
    int8_t m128_i8[16];
    int16_t m128_i16[8];
    int32_t m128_i32[4];
    int64_t m128_i64[2];
    uint8_t m128_u8[16];
    uint16_t m128_u16[8];
    uint32_t m128_u32[4];
} vec4;
typedef union __declspec(align(16)) vec4i{
    uint64_t m128i_u64[2];
    int8_t m128i_i8[16];
    int16_t m128i_i16[8];
    int32_t m128i_i32[4];
    int64_t m128i_i64[2];
    uint8_t m128i_u8[16];
    uint16_t m128i_u16[8];
    uint32_t m128i_u32[4];
} vec4i;

typedef union __declspec(align(16)) vec4d{
    double m128d_f64[2];
} vec4d;
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

On recent clangs, this Just Works without you needing to do anything at all:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

float foo(__m128 x) {
  return x[1];
}
```

AFAIK it Just Works in recent GCC builds as well.

However, I should note the following:

- Consider carefully whether or not you really need to do element-wise access in your vector code.  If you can keep your operations in-lane, they will almost certainly be significantly more efficient.
- If you really do need to do a significant number of lanewise or horizontal operations, **and you don’t need portability**, consider using Clang [extended vectors](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vectors-and-extended-vectors) (or “OpenCL vectors") instead of the basic SSE intrinsic types.  You can pass them to intrinsics just like `__m128` and friends, but they also have much nicer syntax for vector-scalar operations, lane wise operations, vector literals, etc.

Comment: Thnak you. I do not need to do that often, it would kill my performances, currently I'm casting into an array when I need, but on windows, there is this union that makes it easyer (less cast) that thet is much prettier). Also I must be portable woth MSVC, so this compiler option is not really an option.